# Minifying javascript with yahoo minifyer

Tags: javascript, template-builder

I am following [this blog post](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/javascript-compression-in-sdl-tridion/).

It says that you need to deploy the referenced dll's to the Tridion bin folder but when running my TBB in Template Builder it can't find/load the dll's.

I can't find a decent answer if it's possible to do so or that it is mandatory to deploy them in the GAC - that's something I'd rather not do.

Can someone who has experience with referencing third party dll's from a TBB shed some light on this matter please?

[added]

As you can see in the binding information it's only looking in the templating directory. I would have suspected it to look in Tridion\Bin. Created a folder in the `templating` dir for the YUI Compressor so it's loading that one but there must be another way.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = EcmaScript.NET, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/program files (x86)/Tridion/templating/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = TcmTemplateDebugHost.exe
Calling assembly : Yahoo.Yui.Compressor, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\program files (x86)\Tridion\templating\TcmTemplateDebugHost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/program files (x86)/Tridion/templating/EcmaScript.NET.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/program files (x86)/Tridion/templating/EcmaScript.NET/EcmaScript.NET.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/program files (x86)/Tridion/templating/EcmaScript.NET.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/program files (x86)/Tridion/templating/EcmaScript.NET/EcmaScript.NET.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Comment: Did you restart everything once you'd placed the files in the \bin folder?

Comment: Yes the whole shabang. Services, COM+, and IISReset. I can see in the `Assembly Binding Log Viewer` that it's looking in the `templating directory` for the dll's

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've solved it.  If you were executing your template via publishing, then, IIRC the DLLs should be in Tridion/bin or GAC.  However, Template Builder looks for them, as you found out, in the /templating directory.

In my implementation as per the blog post, I believe we put the third-party assembly in the GAC.

Comment: I was trying to not put those third party dll's in the GAC for sake of visibility and managebility, but if it can't be helped it can't be helped.

Comment: Too bad one of the dll's isn't strongly named. Damn  you Yahoo.YUI.Compressor

Comment: Then just put it in both places

Comment: Or grab the source code and compile your own with a strong name (https://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue of referring a 3rd party `DLL` from the templating code. Instead of putting the 3rd party `DLL` in `GAC` which requires approvals from the clients, we used **`ILMerge`** to merge the 3rd party DLL and the templating DLL.

This works perfect.